# How do I find the pivotal quantity?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

**Question**

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from an exponential distribution, $X \sim \operatorname{EXP}(\theta)$ If $\bar{x}=17.9$ with $n=50$, then find a one-sided lower $95 \%$ confidence limit for $\theta$.

**Solution**

The pivotal quantity $\frac{2 n \bar{X}}{\theta} \sim \chi^2(2 n)$ yields $\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{2 n \bar{X}}{\theta}<\chi_\gamma^2\right)=\gamma$ and $\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{2 n \bar{X}}{\chi_\gamma^2}<\theta\right)=\gamma$. With $\chi_\gamma^2(2 n)=\chi_{0.95}^2(100)=124.34$, a one-sided lower $95 \%$ confidence limit for $\theta$ is obtained as
$$
\ell\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right)=\frac{2 n \bar{x}}{\chi_\gamma^2}=\frac{2 \cdot 50 \cdot 17.9}{124.34}=14.396
$$

**Problem**

Currently I am learning about pivotal quantities and the fact that a pivotal quantity is only a function of the data points and the unknown parameter (in this case $\theta$). What I don't understand yet is how the expression $\frac{2 n \bar{X}}{\theta} \sim \chi^2(2 n)$ is derived from the data given in the exercise.

Questions:

- How is the pivotal quantity derived?
- Why is it Chi-squared distributed?

Comment: If $X$ is Exponential with mean $\theta$, then $X/\theta$ is Exp with mean $1$, which implies $2X/\theta$ is Exp with mean $2$. Exp with mean $2$ is same as $\chi^2_2$, and if you add $n$ such independent variables, you get $2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\theta \sim \chi^2_{2n}$.